# jQuery not performing as expected in responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have menu in site and I am using jQuery to create a responsive menu but it's not working. Here's my code:

```js
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("div.cssmenu");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
  "selected": "selected",
  "value": "",
  "text": "Go to..."
}).appendTo("div.cssmenu select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("div.cssmenu a").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  $("<option />", {
    "value": el.attr("href"),
    "text": el.text()
  }).appendTo("div.cssmenu select");
});

$("div.cssmenu select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cssmenu">
  <ul></ul>
  <select>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
    <a href="index.php">
      <option value="">Home</option>
    </a>
    <a href="about?aboutus=aboutus">
      <option value="">About Us</option>
    </a>
    <option value="courses?cosoff=cosoff">Courses Offered</option>
    <option value="admission?admi=admi">Admission</option>
    <option value="facelities?face=face">Facelities</option>
    <option value="events?eve=eve">Events</option>
    <option value="career.php?car=car">Career</option>
    <option value="contact.php?con=con">Contact</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I am using media queries for responsive. It is working fine and this code is working fine except when I select from a dropdown it will select but won't redirect to the specified URL. It's just selecting and nothing happens.

I also tried using `a` tag in first two options of select tag but it's not working. So can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

it's working now but it displaying two dropdown with 1 had twice all the option.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have `a` elements inside a `select`. You should also wrap your code inside a `$(function() {});` block to ensure it runs when the DOM is available. Your `select.change` code block should work fine. Can you provide a non-working example.

Comment: i am using for just checking purpose,without it also not working.

Comment: The browser is ignoring the `<a>` records because they don't belong. So when you try to select them with `$("div.cssmenu a")`, it doesn't find anything.

Comment: a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would help.

Comment: it's working now but it displaying two dropdown with 1 had twice all the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use just

```
$("div.cssmenu select").change(function() {
window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

instead of all above code.